# Combine a list of similar length vectors with NAs to one vector

Tags: r

This is likely a duplicate, yet I appear to be incapable of finding a similar question atm. I have a list of (very long) vectors that are similar in length. Each vector element contains a character. Sometimes multiple vectors contain characters at the same position (sequential numbering from the beginning). Sometimes none contain a character (i.e. all contain NA). There are maybe 10 of these vectors and each has a length of millions of elements. I need to find a quick and memory-efficient way of combining the vectors to a single vector, preferably without using any dependencies (i.e. no data.table or dplyr). The example is simple and short to understand the concept.

I have:

```
x <- list(A = c(rep("A", 5), rep(NA, 5)), B = c(rep(NA, 4), rep("B", 5), NA))
```

I need to combine them to:

```
c(rep("A", 4), "conflict", rep("B", 4), "none")
# "A" "A" "A" "A" "conflict" "B" "B" "B" "B" "none"
```

Thank you for help. I should know how to do this but somehow it escapes me atm. I do have an apply solution that goes in row by row but that is inefficient. Need to vectorize the solution.

```
apply(do.call(cbind, x), 1, function(k) {
  if(sum(is.na(k)) == length(k)) {
    "none"
  } else if (sum(!is.na(k)) == 1) {
    k[!is.na(k)]
  } else {
    "conflict"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorised version of your code :

```
dat <- do.call(cbind, x)
#Logical matrix
mat <- !is.na(dat)
#Number of non-NA's in each row
rs <- rowSums(mat)
#First non-NA value
val <- dat[cbind(1:nrow(dat), max.col(mat, ties.method = 'first'))]
#More than 1 non-NA value
val[rs > 1] <- 'conflict'
#Only NA value
val[rs == 0] <- 'none'
val

#[1] "A"        "A"        "A"        "A"        "Conflict" "B"       
#[7] "B"        "B"        "B"        "none"
```

EDIT - Updated to include suggestion from @Henrik to avoid nested `ifelse` which should make the solution faster.

Comment: Thank you for your anwers everybody. I tried the various alternatives using a relatively small dataset with around 700k elements and 6 vectors. My apply solution took about 2 seconds, RonakShah's vectorized solution 0.3 seconds and @rawr solution 9 seconds. So this solution is 6-7 faster than the apply one I had previously. Accepted :)

Comment: For some reason I thought it was more intuitive to define 'mat' in terms of `!is.na`. Then, instead of two `ifelse`, we can do two replacements in 'val': more than one non-`NA` value: `val[rs > 1] = "conflict"`; no non-`NA` value: `val[rs == 0] = "none"`.

Comment: Yes, that should also be faster. Thanks, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a vectorized function `f` and `Reduce` to apply it to the list. But it assumes that all vectors have the same length. And `Reduce` is not known for its speed-wise performance.

```
f <- function(x, y){
  na.x <- is.na(x) | x == "none"
  na.y <- is.na(y) | y == "none"
  x[na.x & na.y] <- "none"
  x[!na.x & !na.y & x != y] <- "conflict"
  x[!na.x & na.y] <- x[!na.x & na.y]
  x[na.x & !na.y] <- y[na.x & !na.y]
  x
}

Reduce(f, x)
# [1] "A"        "A"        "A"        "A"        "conflict" "B"       
# [7] "B"        "B"        "B"        "none"    
Reduce(f, list(A=NA, B = NA, C = 'A'))
#[1] "A"
```

Comment: @mt1022 Bug corrected, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
x <- list(A = c(rep("A", 5), rep(NA, 5)), B = c(rep(NA, 4), rep("B", 5), NA))
y <- apply(do.call('rbind', x), 2, function(x) toString(na.omit(x)))
y[!nzchar(y)] <- 'none'
replace(y, grepl(',', y), 'conflict')
# [1] "A"        "A"        "A"        "A"        "conflict" "B"        "B"        "B"        "B"        "none"
```